# powershell to create script to get Azure resource cost

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-aks

We need to create a Powershell script to get Azure resources and their cost.

Create a Powershell script to get Azure resources and their cost. I am mostly trying to get VM cost and AKS cost for the resources

Thanks,
Vishnu

Comment: Hi Vishnu; can you share what you've already tried to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck, then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

To get the ***virtual machines*** cost use the below PowerShell script:

```c
$costTotal=0 
$subscriptionId = "209654eb-1867XXXXXX" # Replace with your actual subscription ID
$StartDay = "2023-08-01"
$EndDay = "2023-08-31"

# Get all VMs in the subscription
$vms = Get-AzVM -Status

foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    $vmName = $vm.Name
    $resourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName

    $Consumption = Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName -StartDate $StartDay -EndDate $EndDay -InstanceName $vmName

    $Costs = $Consumption.PretaxCost

    foreach ($Cost in $Costs) {
        $costTotal += $Cost
    }
}

Write-Host "Total cost for all VMs: $costTotal"
```

***Output***:

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/dYutuL8.png)]

When I ran the script, I have only one vm with zero cost like below:

[image]

To check ***Azure Kubernetes*** cost, Make use of below script:

```c
$costTotal = 0
$subscriptionId = "209654eb-1867XXXXXX"
$StartDay = "2023-08-01"
$EndDay = "2023-08-31"

# Connect to your Azure subscription
Connect-AzAccount -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

# Get all AKS clusters in the subscription
$aksClusters = Get-AzAksCluster

foreach ($aksCluster in $aksClusters) {
    $aksName = $aksCluster.Name
    $aksResourceGroupName = $aksCluster.ResourcegroupName

    $Consumption = Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -ResourceGroup $aksResourceGroupName -StartDate $StartDay -EndDate $EndDay -InstanceName $aksName

    $Costs = $Consumption.PretaxCost

    foreach ($Cost in $Costs) {
        $costTotal += $Cost
    }
}

Write-Host "Total cost for all AKS clusters: $($costTotal)"
```

***Output***:

[image]